# WPF DataGrid formatting cell to thousand separators

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have `DataGrid` view in my WPF application which loads data of any given table from any given database. Now I want to convert all numeric values of the table content into thousand separators.

```
 <DataGrid  BorderBrush="Black" Background="White" Margin="10,0,10,10" FontSize="18" BorderThickness="1,0,1,1" RowHeaderWidth="0" x:Name="preview" CanUserAddRows="False" CanUserDeleteRows="False" CanUserReorderColumns="False" CanUserResizeColumns="False" IsTextSearchEnabled="True" IsTextSearchCaseSensitive="False" IsReadOnly="True" CanUserSortColumns="False" FontFamily="Arial" >
    <DataGrid.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ContentControl}">
            <Setter Property="ContentStringFormat" Value="{Binding StringFormat={}{0:N}}"/>
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.Resources>
</DataGrid>
```

But this is not affecting. What is the right way to achieve it?

Comment: Are you using auto-generated columns?

Comment: No. I am not using auto-generated columns!

Comment: You will have to set the StringFormat property on each individual binding. Please refer to my answer. You cannot use an implicit style to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no implcit style that you can apply to all bindings of all columns of a `DataGrid`.

You will have to set the `StringFormat` property on each individual binding. You could do this in the XAML markup if you define the column explicitly, e.g.:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dg" AutoGenerateColumns="False" xmlns:s="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib">
    <DataGrid.Resources>
        <s:String x:Key="format">{0:N}</s:String>
    </DataGrid.Resources>
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="num" Binding="{Binding Num, StringFormat={StaticResource format}}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="num" Binding="{Binding Num2, StringFormat={StaticResource format}}" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Or you could handle the `AutoGeneratingColumn` event, e.g.:

```
private void DataGrid_AutoGeneratingColumn(object sender, DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs e)
{
    DataGridTextColumn col = e.Column as DataGridTextColumn;
    if (col != null && e.PropertyType == typeof(decimal) || e.PropertyType == typeof(double))
    {
        col.Binding = new Binding(e.PropertyName) { StringFormat = "{0:N}" };
    }
}
```

Comment: But I don't know the table structure and column data types in advance as they are of any database and of any table.

Comment: If you don't know the table structure you must be auto-generating the columns? Then you could handle the AutoGeneratingColumn event as I suggested in the answer. You could implement the event handler however you want. The above code was just an example.

Comment: Thanks! I am new to WPF. Let me try this.

Comment: What if property type is string but data is in the numeric type?

Comment: You cannot apply a StringFormat to a string.

Comment: Hi, Your solution is worked for me! But I want specific format in which I have to convert that number.

Comment: I am editing my question so you will get to know what I am expecting.

Comment: Please ask a new question if you have another issue. And please remember to accept the answer and vote it up if your *orignal* issue has been solved.

Comment: Best answer ever. Thank you @mm8.